# How to get developerToken for google adwords api?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I've downloaded the PHP client library for Google Adwords API. I need to insert my login details in `/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/auth.ini`. One of the variable is **developerToken**.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 3):

Directly from the API...

> Your assigned Developer Token will be activated once your application
>   for API access is approved. **Your token will be available through your
>   AdWords API Center—accessible through the My Account menu for the MCC
>   account you applied with**. You'll be able to access the API by
>   including it in your request headers when interacting with our system.
>
> It is very important that you keep your Contact Email up to date—we
>   may send you important information regarding disruptions to service
>   and urgent changes via this channel.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/signingup

Comment: it says "You can sign up for the AdWords API when logged into your MCC account. Navigate to My Account -> AdWords API Center and follow the instructions to apply for AdWords API access." But I don't see the link to "Adwords API Center" under "My Account"

Comment: @user2413761 Same issue here. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I got mine but it took a few days for it appear. Now I'm trying to figure out the test account.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this might be old, but since Google updated their API, let me share my experience.

You need to create an MCC account (My Client Center), basically if you already have a Google Adwords account you cannot use it to generate *developerToken* however, you still can you use same Gmail account to create a new MCC account.

Follow below:

1. https://adwords.google.com/home/tools/manager-accounts/
2. Click on *Start Now*
3. Probably you are already logged in using your Gmail account, in all cases use your Gmail account in the email address field.
4. Choose name for your account let's say *main-account*
5. Do not click *save and continue*
6. Check below picture, you need to click, *click here* in the message below.
7. You will then redirect to the main dashboard, where you can click on *Tools* and then under *SETUP* tab you will find *Adwords API Centre* where you will be able to generate developerToken

[image: Check out this message, it will only be available if you are already logged in using your Google Account]

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the developer token from your live account. The token will work fine even if its status is pending